# Flux intervals not able to retrieve back on next

Tags: project-reactor

I want to create a map of flux intervals which will be called based on the time set in flux interval every day. I tried creating flux interval and saving that associated disposal against a key in map but how do i retrieve that dispoable back?

I tried Flux.interval and saved it to map<string,disposable> but i  unable to retrieve that disposable

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cannot get the idea what you want to achieve with this, but I don't see any problem to add your Disposable to the map after you subscribed to your reactive chain.

Here is an example:

```java
Disposable firstDisposable = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000L))
        .subscribe();
Disposable secondDisposable = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
        .subscribe();

Map<String, Disposable> disposableMap =
        Map.of("first", firstDisposable, "second", secondDisposable);

System.out.println(String.format("Map size: %s", disposableMap.size()));
System.out.println(disposableMap.get("first"));
System.out.println(disposableMap.get("second"));
```

Which will print you the following proving that everything is ok:

```
Map size: 2
reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber@585811a4
reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber@22c01ab0
```